# How to get List name in android list view?

Tags: android, listview

I have one list view and two list. I am loading one list(List  list1) at the time of loading.After clicking that list item i am loading another list(List  list2)

My requirement i want to know which list is displaying in the list view.That means i want the list name present in the list view

Comment: You want to know in the code, or to display to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using two adapters - can you not use getAdapter() find which adapter is in use at any time?

Comment: thanks for your reply.But i am using single adapter for both?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ListView.addHeaderView(View v)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) to add some title/header to the list. It is up to you what you use as that view. Looks like `TextView` is the best candidate.

Answer (score 0):

you can send your list name through your adapter constructor and then do whatever you want with it..